# Unable to understand the two definitions of derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, definition

At some places I find the definition of derivative like this:

$$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac {f(x)-f(a)} {x-a}$$

While at some other places its different as you can see below:

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)} {h}$$

So I am confused, please help me in understanding these.

Comment: Please don't use images.

Comment: Set $h=x-a$ and do a change of variable.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, Ok , I will not use images next time. Thanks for your comments. Regards

Answer (score 1):

The usual definition of the derivative is $$f'(a)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac {f(x)-f(a)} {x-a}$$ I feel like this definition is easier to remember as it matches the idea of the slope of a tangent line to a point. But sometimes the other definition is also useful. The way we make that definition is by defining a new variable $h=x-a$.

In the previous limit we wanted to evaluate the expression $$\frac{f(x)-f(a)} {x-a}$$ for values of $x$ near $a$. If we wish to use the variable $h=x-a$, then we need to take the limit where $h\to 0$ as that corresponds to $x$ getting near $a$. So, the new limit becomes $$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x)-f(a)} {h}$$ But one thing we missed was the value of $x$. Since we defined $h=x-a$, we see that $x=h+a$. So the above limit could be written as $$f'(a)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac {f(a+h)-f(a)} {h}$$

It's just that one expression is easier to evaluate in place of the other. Try both of them when you need to evaluate a derivative and see which one works.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly where the $h$ comes from. In the second formula they have also changed the $a$ to $x_0$. But those are just two different names for the same thing. If you write $x_0$ you get exactly what the second web page said.